# Using a variable to select multiple columns in select (dplyr)

Tags: r, tidyverse

With dplyr, when I want to select multiple columns in a range, I can usually do something like this:

```
dplyr::select(data, column1:column7)
```

However, I'm writing a function where the user will input the column names as a variable, like:

```
colnames <- "column1:column7"
```

Obviously, this won't work:

```
dplyr::select(data,  colnames)
```

But what will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible you can take two separate inputs from the user. We can then generate a sequence of column numbers between them using `match`.

For example using base R, with `mtcars` dataset

```
col1 <- 'mpg'
col2 <- 'am'
mtcars[match(col1, names(mtcars)) : match(col2, names(mtcars))]

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
#...
```

If you can't have separate input you could split the combined input on `":"`.

```
col <- 'mpg:am'
col <- strsplit(col, ":")[[1]]
```

and now you can use `col[1]` as `col1` and `col[2]` as `col2` in above method.

```
mtcars[match(col[1], names(mtcars)) : match(col[2], names(mtcars))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select_at`, but the search string you have is not standard. So you will have to do some work on it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
colnames <- map2("column",1:7,paste0) %>% unlist
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=7,nrow=2))
colnames(data) <- colnames
select_at(data,colnames)
#  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
#1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Here I'm using `purrr` and `rlang` for convenience. You could use base R functions too.

```
searchstring <- "column1:column7"
replacedstring <- gsub("column","",searchstring)
sequence <- eval_tidy(parse_expr(replacedstring))
parsedcolumns <- map_chr(sequence,~ paste0("column",.x))
select_at(data,parsedcolumns)
  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Note that evaluating random code provided by users is dangerous. I'd recommend finding another way to have the user enter data.